# delete value immediate after specific value in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where data is like below and I want to delete immediate row after row where this value is available -1e38

Actually -1e38 value is signal that the row before -1e38 is invalid.

Please help.

```
 declare @tbl table (id int, ex_date date, value float, final_date date)

 insert into @tbl 
 values(1,'2018-02-10',-1e38,'2018-03-30'),
       (1,'2018-02-28',10,'2018-03-30'),
       (1,'2018-02-28',12,'2018-03-30'),
       (1,'2018-01-29',-1e38,'2018-03-31'),
       (1,'2018-01-29',19,'2018-01-30'),
       (1,'2018-01-29',22,'2018-01-30'),
       (1,'2018-01-29',22,'2018-01-31')

select * 
from @tbl 
order by final_date desc, ex_date desc
```

Should be deleted :

```
  1 2018-01-29  -1E+38  2018-03-31
  1 2018-02-28  10  2018-03-30
```

Should not be deleted :

```
  1 2018-02-28  12  2018-03-30
```

Should be deleted :

```
  1 2018-02-10  -1E+38  2018-03-30
  1 2018-01-29  22  2018-01-31
```

Should not be deleted :

```
  1 2018-01-29  19  2018-01-30
  1 2018-01-29  22  2018-01-30
```

Comment: "row before -1e38 is invalid" - I presume this should say after, since everything else in your post is indicating that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, when we order by the date the row, is showing after but actually, it is before that date where error term is mentioned.

Comment: Pick *an order* and make your post consistent, please, is all I'm asking for.

Comment: It looks like extremely bad design and code smell. Are all ID's same? What is the order? Hint: use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I've grasped your requirements. This *selects* 5 rows, not including those appearing immediately after a -1e38 row, based on the ordering you specified for your select:

```
declare @tbl table (id int , ex_date date, value float, final_date date)
insert into @tbl values
(1,'2018-02-10',-1e38,'2018-03-30'),
(1,'2018-02-28',10,'2018-03-30'),
(1,'2018-02-28',12,'2018-03-30'),
(1,'2018-01-29',-1e38,'2018-03-31'),
(1,'2018-01-29',19,'2018-01-30'),
(1,'2018-01-29',22,'2018-01-30'),
(1,'2018-01-29',22,'2018-01-31')

;With Numbered as (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by final_date desc, ex_date desc ) as rn
from @tbl
)
select
    n1.*
from
    Numbered n1
        left join
    Numbered n2
        on
            n1.rn = n2.rn + 1
where
    (n2.id is null or n2.value != -1e38)
    /* and n1.value != -1e38 --? */
order by final_date desc, ex_date desc
```

Results:

```
id          ex_date    value                  final_date rn
----------- ---------- ---------------------- ---------- --------------------
1           2018-01-29 -1E+38                 2018-03-31 1
1           2018-02-28 12                     2018-03-30 3
1           2018-02-10 -1E+38                 2018-03-30 4
1           2018-01-29 19                     2018-01-30 6
1           2018-01-29 22                     2018-01-30 7
```

If you're also wanting to exclude the rows containing `-1e38` then uncomment the extra `WHERE` clause condition above.

If you're actually wanting to delete the rows, replace `select *` with `delete n1`, remove the `order by` and invert the `where` clause conditions:

```
delete n1
from
    Numbered n1
        left join
    Numbered n2
        on
            n1.rn = n2.rn + 1
where
    n2.value = -1e38
    or n1.value = -1e38
```